# "System Program problem detected"-->"Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, openstack

I'm really newbie to linux, so I'd be glad with a step by step answer.

I'm using ubuntu 15.10 (recently upgraded)

Perhaps I should emphasize that the upgrade didn't complete well or totally because my laptop shut off (core temperature too high) during the process (when it was almost done).

Now, everything I try to install or update, terminates with the same error (`Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`), as shown bellow.

Because of this, the system is popping the message "System Program problem detected" everytime the system initiates.

I've tried all the other solutions given in the possible duplicates but none worked.

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

```
Log started: 2016-03-28  18:28:24  

Selecting previously unselected
 package compiz-plugins:amd64.

(Reading database ...  
(Reading
 database ... 5% 
(Reading database ... 10% 
(Reading database ... 15%

 (Reading database ... 20% (Reading database ... 25% (Reading database
 ... 30% (Reading database ... 35% (Reading database ... 40% (Reading
 database ... 45% (Reading database ... 50% (Reading database ... 55%
 (Reading database ... 60% (Reading database ... 65% (Reading database
 ... 70% (Reading database ... 75% (Reading database ... 80% (Reading
 database ... 85% (Reading database ... 90% (Reading database ... 95%
 (Reading database ... 100% (Reading database ... 311327 files and
 directories currently installed.)  Preparing to unpack
 .../compiz-plugins_1%3a0.9.12.2+15.10.20151202-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ... 
 Unpacking compiz-plugins:amd64 (1:0.9.12.2+15.10.20151202-0ubuntu1)
 ...  Selecting previously unselected package compiz-plugins-extra. 
 Preparing to unpack
 .../compiz-plugins-extra_1%3a0.9.12.2+15.10.20151202-0ubuntu1_all.deb
 ...  Unpacking compiz-plugins-extra
 (1:0.9.12.2+15.10.20151202-0ubuntu1) ...  Setting up
 openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme (2:8.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...  Collecting
 and compressing static assets...  ***Job for apache2.service invalid. 
 dpkg: error processing package openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
 (--configure):   subprocess installed post-installation script
 returned error exit status 1***  Setting up compiz-plugins:amd64
 (1:0.9.12.2+15.10.20151202-0ubuntu1) ...  Setting up
 compiz-plugins-extra (1:0.9.12.2+15.10.20151202-0ubuntu1) ...  ***Errors
 were encountered while processing:   openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme*** 
 Log ended: 2016-03-28  18:30:47   

 Log started: 2016-03-28  18:59:10 
 Selecting previously unselected package python-xlib.  (Reading
 database ...  (Reading database ... 5% (Reading database ... 10%
 (Reading database ... 15% (Reading database ... 20% (Reading database
 ... 25% (Reading database ... 30% (Reading database ... 35% (Reading
 database ... 40% (Reading database ... 45% (Reading database ... 50%
 (Reading database ... 55% (Reading database ... 60% (Reading database
 ... 65% (Reading database ... 70% (Reading database ... 75% (Reading
 database ... 80% (Reading database ... 85% (Reading database ... 90%
 (Reading database ... 95% (Reading database ... 100% (Reading database
 ... 311462 files and directories currently installed.)  Preparing to
 unpack .../python-xlib_0.14+20091101-5_all.deb ...  Unpacking
 python-xlib (0.14+20091101-5) ...  Selecting previously unselected
 package key-mon.  Preparing to unpack
 .../key-mon_1.17-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...  Unpacking key-mon
 (1.17-1ubuntu1) ...  Processing triggers for gnome-menus
 (3.13.3-6ubuntu1) ...  Processing triggers for bamfdaemon
 (0.5.2~bzr0+15.10.20150627.1-0ubuntu1) ...  Rebuilding
 /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...  Processing triggers for
 desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...  Processing triggers for
 mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...  Processing triggers for
 hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...  Processing triggers for man-db
 (2.7.4-1) ...  Setting up openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
 (2:8.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...  Collecting and compressing static assets... 
 ***Job for apache2.service invalid.  dpkg: error processing package
 openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme (--configure):   subprocess installed
 post-installation script returned error exit status 1***  Setting up
 python-xlib (0.14+20091101-5) ...  Setting up key-mon (1.17-1ubuntu1)
 ...  Log ended: 2016-03-28  19:01:47    

Log started: 2016-03-28 
 19:21:58  Setting up openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
 (2:8.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...  Collecting and compressing static assets... 
 Job for apache2.service invalid.  dpkg: error processing package
 openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme (--configure):   subprocess installed
 post-installation script returned error exit status 1  Errors were
 encountered while processing:   openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme  
Log ended: 2016-03-28  19:23:33   

 Log started: 2016-03-29  13:02:17 
 Selecting previously unselected package lm-sensors.  (Reading database
 ...  (Reading database ... 5% (Reading database ... 10% (Reading
 database ... 15% (Reading database ... 20% (Reading database ... 25%
 (Reading database ... 30% (Reading database ... 35% (Reading database
 ... 40% (Reading database ... 45% (Reading database ... 50% (Reading
 database ... 55% (Reading database ... 60% (Reading database ... 65%
 (Reading database ... 70% (Reading database ... 75% (Reading database
 ... 80% (Reading database ... 85% (Reading database ... 90% (Reading
 database ... 95% (Reading database ... 100% (Reading database ...
 311846 files and directories currently installed.)  Preparing to
 unpack .../lm-sensors_1%3a3.4.0-2_amd64.deb ...  Unpacking lm-sensors
 (1:3.4.0-2) ...  Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ... 
 Processing triggers for systemd (225-1ubuntu9.1) ...  Processing
 triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...  ureadahead will be
 reprofiled on next reboot  Setting up openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
 (2:8.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...  Collecting and compressing static assets... 
 Job for apache2.service invalid.  dpkg: error processing package
 openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme (--configure):   subprocess installed
 post-installation script returned error exit status 1  Setting up
 lm-sensors (1:3.4.0-2) ...  Processing triggers for systemd
 (225-1ubuntu9.1) ...  Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19)
 ...  Errors were encountered while processing:  
 openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme Log ended: 2016-03-29  13:04:00   

 Log started: 2016-03-29  13:21:29  Setting up
 openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme (2:8.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...  Collecting
 and compressing static assets...  Job for apache2.service invalid. 
 dpkg: error processing package openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
 (--configure):   subprocess installed post-installation script
 returned error exit status 1  Errors were encountered while
 processing:   openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme  Log ended: 2016-03-29 
 13:22:39    Log started: 2016-03-29  13:34:19  Setting up
 openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme (2:8.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...  Collecting
 and compressing static assets...  Job for apache2.service invalid. 
 dpkg: error processing package openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
 (--configure):   subprocess installed post-installation script
 returned error exit status 1  Errors were encountered while
 processing:   openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme  Log ended: 2016-03-29 
 13:35:31    

Log started: 2016-03-29  14:05:31  Selecting previously
 unselected package reduce-algebra-fonts.  (Reading database ... 
 (Reading database ... 5% (Reading database ... 10% (Reading database
 ... 15% (Reading database ... 20% (Reading database ... 25% (Reading
 database ... 30% (Reading database ... 35% (Reading database ... 40%
 (Reading database ... 45% (Reading database ... 50% (Reading database
 ... 55% (Reading database ... 60% (Reading database ... 65% (Reading
 database ... 70% (Reading database ... 75% (Reading database ... 80%
 (Reading database ... 85% (Reading database ... 90% (Reading database
 ... 95% (Reading database ... 100% (Reading database ... 311881 files
 and directories currently installed.)  Preparing to unpack
 .../reduce-algebra-fonts_20110414-1~getdeb2_all.deb ...  Unpacking
 reduce-algebra-fonts (20110414-1~getdeb2) ...  Selecting previously
 unselected package reduce-algebra.  Preparing to unpack
 .../reduce-algebra_20110414-1~getdeb2_amd64.deb ...  Unpacking
 reduce-algebra (20110414-1~getdeb2) ...  Selecting previously
 unselected package reduce-algebra-docs.  Preparing to unpack
 .../reduce-algebra-docs_20110414-1~getdeb2_all.deb ...  Unpacking
 reduce-algebra-docs (20110414-1~getdeb2) ...  Processing triggers for
 gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu1) ...  Processing triggers for bamfdaemon
 (0.5.2~bzr0+15.10.20150627.1-0ubuntu1) ...  Rebuilding
 /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...  Processing triggers for
 desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...  Processing triggers for
 mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...  Setting up
 openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme (2:8.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...  Collecting
 and compressing static assets...  Job for apache2.service invalid. 
 dpkg: error processing package openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
 (--configure):   subprocess installed post-installation script
 returned error exit status 1  Setting up reduce-algebra-fonts
 (20110414-1~getdeb2) ...  Setting up reduce-algebra
 (20110414-1~getdeb2) ...  Setting up reduce-algebra-docs
 (20110414-1~getdeb2) ...  Errors were encountered while processing:  
 openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme  Log ended: 2016-03-29  14:08:13
```

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be `dpkg-reconfigure` package-name' but i doubt it will work. You can still give it a shot.

Also try `sudo apt-get -f install` (-f for fix) and if that does not help, I'd try removing some packages that won't update/install. After removal you can install them again. The settings won't be lost unless you use --purge.

But be careful about that and always use `-s`first (-s for simulate) to see the resulting actions. Don't un-install packages that are are requirement of many other packages.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But after trying a lot of things, I decided to do a fresh install... Not a very helpful feedback, but...

Comment: i can relate... but the above commands saved one or two installations in the past, that had not been updated in a while or used too much experimental stuff